# PHP Post, Redirect, Get Issues

Tags: php, session, firefox, safari

I created a form that takes your birthday and spits out a bunch of data relative to that date. Everything works great in chrome, but I'm not getting an output in browsers like firefox and safari. I'm also not receiving any php errors, but I think the problem is that FF & safari are not setting the session variables as intended. I'm new to PHP so this is my first time using this method, but here's what I'm currently using:
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);

```
if(count($_POST) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['dob-month'] = $_POST['dob-month'];
    $_SESSION['dob-day'] = $_POST['dob-day'];
    $_SESSION['dob-year'] = $_POST['dob-year'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $_SESSION['submit'] = 1;
    }

    header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    die();
}
elseif (isset($_SESSION['dob-month'])||isset($_SESSION['dob-day'])||isset($_SESSION['dob-year'])){
    $month = $_SESSION['dob-month'];
    $day = ltrim(sanitizeNumInput($_SESSION['dob-day']),'0');

    $year = sanitizeNumInput($_SESSION['dob-year']);
    $submit = $_SESSION['submit'];

    /*
        Put database-affecting code here.
    */

    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}else{
    $month = 0;
    $day = 0;
    $year = 0;  
}
```

**Form**

```
<form method="post" id="birthday-form" action="/calculator/">
    <div class="dobRow">
        <div class="dobMonth">
            <select name="dob-month">
                <option value="">Month</option>
                <option value="1">January</option>
                <option value="2">February</option>
                <option value="3">March</option>
                <option value="4">April</option>
                <option value="5">May</option>
                <option value="6">June</option>
                <option value="7">July</option>
                <option value="8">August</option>
                <option value="9">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div class="dobDay">
            <input type="text" name="dob-day" maxlength="2" placeholder="Day"/>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div class="dobYear">
            <input type="text" maxlength="4" max="2015" name="dob-year" placeholder="Year"/>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div class="dobSubmit">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate"/>
        </div>

        <!-- <p> erroneous -->
    </div>
    <p></p>
</form>
```

The line after the session start was just thrown in there to check php errors, and I'm currently not receiving any. I was receiving undefined variable errors for $month, $day, and $year on the initial page load before the sessions had been set, which is why they are set to 0 by default.

If someone could help me figure out why this isn't working correctly I'd really appreciate the help. I've been trying to get this function to work correctly all weekend, but I'm struggling and not sure what else to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output are you getting in Chrome?

Comment: @xcvd The output i'm getting in chrome is the expected end result, which should be data relative to the birthday entered. The overall function basically takes a birthday, validates, and then executes calculations relative to the birthday data.

Comment: The $_POST array is never set in FF & safari for some reason.

Comment: Post your form markup.

Comment: @xcvd I added the form block from FF.

Comment: I don't get why the server side script works fine in one browser, but not the others. Could it have anything to do with the header redirection?